# ffmpeg based JAVE video conversion taking a long time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, transcoding, performance

I am using ffmpeg to convert videos to mp4 format in my application I have used JAVE and Xuggler for the same. My issue is that, video conversions are taking way too much of time. For example, a 50MB video takes almost 2 hrs to complete the video conversion and upload the same. Also, when i play a video, it takes a longer time to play on safari on mac OS than chrome/firefox.

What are the possible solutions for this? How to optimize the conversion time/video buffering for playing the video faster

I am using the it.sauronsoftware.jave.VideoAttributes and EncodingAttributes classes to do this

```
VideoAttributes video = new VideoAttributes();
video.setCodec("libx264");
EncodingAttributes attributes = new EncodingAttributes();
attributes.setFormat("mp4");
attributes.setVideoAttributes(video);
Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new FFMPEGLocator() {
                @Override
                protected String getFFMPEGExecutablePath() {
        String ffmpegPath = PropertiesUtil
            .getProperty("location.ffmpeg");
        return ffmpegPath;
     }
});
encoder.encode(sourceFile, destFile, attributes);
```

sourceFile and destFile are the source and destination files respectively

Comment: Please paste the ffmpeg command as well as the console output.

Comment: @Mulvya, I have included the java code used to do the conversion

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help much. Need to know the actual syntax that ffmpeg is being invoked with.

Comment: @Mulvya, In my case the java code invokes the FFMPEG instance installed in the system for the conversion process. How will i get to know the exact command that ffmpeg invokes?

Comment: Not familiar with JAVE. Perhaps you can ask the developer Carlo Pelliccia at cpelliccia@sauronsoftware.it